# Clean & efficient bounding box non-intersection test

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, computational-geometry

I would like a quick test to tell me that segments $ab$ and $cd$ cannot intersect in the plane. If the maximum $x$-coordinate of $a$ and $b$ is less than the minimum $x$-coordinate of $c$ and $d$, then they cannot intersect. Etc.:

```
max = Max[a[[1]], b[[1]]];
min = Min[c[[1]], d[[1]]];
(*ab leftof cd*)
If[max < min, Return[False]];
max = Max[c[[1]], d[[1]]];
min = Min[a[[1]], b[[1]]];
(*cd leftof ab*)
If[max < min, Return[False]];
...
```

I feel this is rather clumsy coding. What is (a) a more concise coding, and (b) recognizing this is for speed, a more efficient bounding-box rejection.

The same question can be asked for $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d>2$
(athough then it would likely be higher-dimensional objects determining
the bounding box).

Comment: I'm in a hurry and I am not quite sure if I understood what you were asking or not, but, if I understand, you might try using `RegionIntersection` and compare that with `EmptyRegion`. It would look clean, but I'm not sure how it would do performance-wise.

Comment: There is, as I recall, an undocumented routine for generating axis-aligned bounding boxes, which as you know can be wasteful. I don't remember any function for oriented boxes being built-in.

Comment: Let me know if I am misunderstanding you, but if you are wanting to test if two line segments intersect, you can use IntersectQ[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Not[SameQ[RegionIntersection[Line[{a, b}], Line[{c, d}]], EmptyRegion[n]]] where a-d are points and n is their dimension. If you just want the box surrounding them, then you can use   RegionBounds[RegionUnion[Line[{a, b}], Line[{c, d}]]]

Comment: @BenP1192 you should post that as an answer. I found that you can include the bounding box in `RegionIntersection`, `RegionIntersection[Line[ab], Line[cd], Rectangle[]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following points a-f, which form the line segments ab and cd and ef.

```
a = {0, 0};
b = {3, 3};
c = {1, .5};
d = {2, 1.5};
e = {0, 2};
f = {2, 0};
```

[image: Picture of line segments]

In order to test whether they intersect you can use `RegionIntersection`. First form lines from your points, then use `RegionIntersection` on the two lines. Compare the intersection to an empty region to see if the lines intersect. I built the following functions for 2D points, but you can change that by specifying a different dimension for `EmptyRegion`

```
IntersectQ[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Not[SameQ[RegionIntersection[Line[{a, b}],
 Line[{c, d}]], EmptyRegion[2]]]

IntersectQ[a,b,c,d];
(*False*)
IntersectQ[a,b,e,f];
(*True*)
```

The evaluation was quick when I ran it, around 0.014 seconds.

As AndyRoss mentioned, you can use a variety of shapes within the intersection to suit your needs.

If you need to find the box surrounding the lines, use the following:

```
 RegionBounds[RegionUnion[Line[{a, b}], Line[{c, d}]]]
```

Comment: Very nice---Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with M11.1 you can use [`RegionDisjoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint):

```
a = {0, 0};
b = {3, 3};
c = {1, .5};
d = {2, 1.5};
e = {0, 2};
f = {2, 0};

Not @ RegionDisjoint[Line[{a, b}], Line[{c, d}]] //RepeatedTiming
Not @ RegionDisjoint[Line[{a, b}], Line[{e, f}]] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0020, False}
>
> {0.00083, True}

Compare to the accepted answer:

```
IntersectQ[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Not[
    SameQ[RegionIntersection[Line[{a, b}], Line[{c, d}]], EmptyRegion[2]]
]

IntersectQ[a,b,c,d] //RepeatedTiming
IntersectQ[a,b,e,f] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0035, False}
>
> {0.0023, True}